# Update only part of graphics

Tags: vb.net, graphics, refresh

I wonder, is there an easy way to update only a part of graphics? In the example bellow, I drew 1560 small squares 10x10px each and painted blue 3 of them. This takes some considerable time (circa 1sec), one can see how they are painted on the screen. In the next step, I'd like to shift the 3 blue squares to a different position, meaning I want to keep all drawn graphics, but **paint only 3 squares back to gray and paint another 3 sqares to blue**.
If I repaint the picture completely, it takes a "lot" of time, approx. the 1 sec. mentioned above. I would like to reach at least few frames per second, as I'm doing a small "animated" simulation. This means, that the code doesn't have to be sexy, but simple enough to be used in a program with very short live.

[image: Pattern of squares]

The method sketched in Button4_click code is fast, but just because paints **only** the new squares, wiping out the old graphics.

Note, that I paint onto a Panel1, not PictureBox1, as is adviced due to performance (avoiding some unnesessary event handlers and refreshes).

Sketched test code:

```
Private drawPattern As Boolean = False
Private drawBlueRects As Boolean = False
Dim blueBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
Dim grayBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Gray)

Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    If drawPattern Then
        Dim StartY As Integer = 250 - 60 ' just set Y for upper set of squares
        For ir = 1 To 6                  ' paint upper set of squares
            For ic = 0 To 120
                g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.Gray), 5 + ic * 10, StartY + ir * 10, 8, 8)
            Next
        Next ir
        StartY = 250 + 10  ' just set Y for bottom set of squares
        For ir = 1 To 6    ' paint bottom set of squares
            For ic = 0 To 120
                g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.Gray), 5 + ic * 10, StartY + ir * 10, 8, 8)
            Next
        Next ir
        For ic = 0 To 120  ' paint middle set of squares
            g.FillRectangle(grayBrush, 5 + ic * 10, 250 + 10, 8, 8)
        Next
        ' paint 3 blue squares
        g.FillRectangle(blueBrush, 155, 250 + 10, 8, 8)
        g.FillRectangle(blueBrush, 165, 250 + 10, 8, 8)
        g.FillRectangle(blueBrush, 175, 250 + 10, 8, 8)
    ElseIf drawBlueRects = True Then
        ' paint 3 blue squares
        g.FillRectangle(blueBrush, 255, 250 + 10, 8, 8)
        g.FillRectangle(blueBrush, 265, 250 + 10, 8, 8)
        g.FillRectangle(blueBrush, 275, 250 + 10, 8, 8)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    drawPattern = True
    Panel1.Refresh()
    'Panel1.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    drawPattern = False
    drawBlueRects = True
    Panel1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

I apologize, if I misgoogled a ready solution; please provide a link in such case.

Regards,

Libor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Invalidate` method of a control specifies that a particular area of the control needs to be repainted and the `Update` method initiates a repaint.  The `Refresh` method simply calls `Invalidate` with no parameters, indicating that the whole control needs repainting, and then calls `Update`.  Instead of `Refresh`, call `Invalidate` and `Update` yourself.  That way, you can pass an appropriate argument to `Invalidate` to specify exactly what part or parts of the control to redraw.  You can call `Invalidate` multiple times for a complex area or areas.

Comment: I decided to mark this as correct answer, because it is. However, I got around the issue, which I explain bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by a workaround - I draw into a bitmap and update the PictureBox with this bitmap everytime I change it. Since I can draw to particular location of the bitmap, there are no issues with re-drawing:

Define bitmap in the class heading:

```
Dim bm As New Bitmap(1910, 500)
```

Initial drawing:

```
Private Sub CreateImage()
    Dim w As Integer = bm.Width ' or PictureBox1.Width
    Dim h As Integer = bm.Height  ' or PictureBox1.Height
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(w, h, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    bm = bmp
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)  ' get it from current state of bitmap
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
        Dim Ypos As Integer = 0
        Call DrawRecArray(StartY - 100, g, NoOfBaysInSet)
        Call DrawRecArray(StartY + 10, g, NoOfBaysInSet)
        For ic = 0 To icLimit   ' paint middle set of squares
            g.FillRectangle(grayBrush, 5 + ic * 10, StartY + 10, 8, 8)
            Call DrawStringFunc(5 + ic * 10, StartY - 70 + Ypos * 5, ic + 1, g, drawFont)
            Ypos += 1
            If Ypos = 3 Then Ypos = 0
            If Ypos = 1 Then Call DrawStringFunc(5 + ic * 10, StartY - 90 + Ypos * 5, (ic + 1 * 3) / 3, g, drawFontB)
        Next
    End Using
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp  ' put the bitmap into Picturebox !!!
End Sub
```

Updating the bitmap:

```
Private Sub UpdateImage(FromPos As Int16, ToPos As Int16)
    Dim w As Integer = bm.Width
    Dim h As Integer = bm.Height
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.PictureBox1.Image) ' now get the bitmap from the PictureBox
    bm = bmp
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
        g.FillRectangle(backBrush, 5 + FromPos * 10, StartY + 10, 28, 8)
        g.FillRectangle(grayBrush, 5 + FromPos * 10, StartY + 10, 8, 8)
        g.FillRectangle(grayBrush, 15 + FromPos * 10, StartY + 10, 8, 8)
        g.FillRectangle(grayBrush, 25 + FromPos * 10, StartY + 10, 8, 8)
        g.FillRectangle(blueBrush, 5 + ToPos * 10, StartY + 10, 28, 8)
    End Using
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp  ' update pictureBox with modified bitmap
End Sub
```

I believe this is a valued answer. I deal with GDI for quite few years and bump into this issue repeatedly and out of many thousands answers, only few describe redrawing without _paint event, which I believe is usesless for such cases. Most of the samples are one-off drawings.

Regards

Libor